# Automatic update records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I would like to update a record based on a his column for example I have a table that has a `DateEnd` column, and when I got a value in `DateEnd`, it should automatically modify another column of that row.

It would be better to do this in SQL or progrgamação ?

Comment: Look up SQL triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use trigger

```
ALTER TRIGGER trgAfterUpdate ON [dbo].[Employee]
FOR UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE
AS
    SELECT 'DO SOMETHING AT THIS STATEMENT',* FROM INSERTED
GO
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft SQL Management studio, if you go to the design of your table and on the properties on the "Default Value" property and set it to be GetDate() that will set the column value to be the date that any column is changed...

You can do it through TSQL Too:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.doc_exz ( column_a INT, column_b INT) ;
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.doc_exz (column_a)VALUES ( 7 ) ;
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.doc_exz
ADD CONSTRAINT col_b_def
DEFAULT GetDate() FOR column_b ;
GO
```

One thing to note is that this only will work on Insert new rows, for Updates you could use Triggers to do what you are looking for.

Comment: That's not correct.  Setting a default on a column will only populate on an INSERT if no data is supplied for the column. Updating the row will not change the column value, unless you provide that value.

Comment: Yeah, that's right, default is for inserts. for updates Triggers will do

Answer (score 0):

Either trigger or computed column would help you in this case.